# Find number of unique words in Paragraph tags using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, function, beautifulsoup

I'm very new to python.I'm trying to implement a function which outputs the number of unique words inside the paragraph tags but after editing these text in few ways.
First: Retrieve all text enclosed in paragraph tags and convert them to lower case
second: Strip out punctuation for which I'm using `str.translate(str.maketrans('','',string.punctuation))`
Third: Tokenize into words based on whitespace separation.
Fourth: output number of unique words.

Here's my code:

```
import urllib
def getLength(url):
    r=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
    links = soup.find_all('p')
    k=[]
    for p in links:
        if not p.find('a'):
            pText = p.get_text()
            k=k.append(pText)
        k=k.lower()
        translator=str.translate(str.maketrans('','',string.punctuation))
        k=k.translate(translator)
    #missing code
getLength("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google")
```

I tried printing values and found that my logic is incorrect. I don't know how to correct this and proceed further. Please help.

edit:

```
import urllib
def getLength(url):
    r=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
    links = soup.find_all('p')
    for p in links:
        pText = p.get_text()
        pText=pText.lower()
        transpText=pText.translate(pText.maketrans('','',string.punctuation))
        print(transpText)
        newdata=transpText.split()
        length=len(newdata)
        return length
getLength("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google")
```

I got this, but i didn't understand the tokenization part. And for some reason I'm getting 0 as the length. What did i do wrong or how should this be done.

Comment: hi @JBlack, welcome to SO. You've mentionned [logic error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_error). To put a good question, you need 1) the input 2) the output of your function 3) What the function is supposed to do. With it, the troubleshooting will be easier for the one who will be helping you.

Comment: You're looking for the collections module. https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects

Comment: You cannot call `.lower()` or `.translate()` on a list (`k` is a list); call it on `pText` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import urllib
def getLength(url):
    r=urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
    links = soup.find_all('p')
    k=[]
for p in links:
    pText = p.get_text()
    pText=pText.lower()
    transpText=pText.translate(pText.maketrans('','',string.punctuation))
    newdata=transpText.split()
    k += newdata
n=np.unique(k)
return len(n)
getLength("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google")
```

After trying multiple times...this code is what i landed on and it seems to work properly for various test cases.